# Auto-generated FK relations in EF Core - how to made them non-nullable

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, entity-framework-core-migrations, entity-framework-core-3.1

I have the following model:

```
public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Childs { get; set; }
}
```

Without any further instructing, EF Core 3.1 automatically infers the reference relation between `Parent` and `Child`, and generates the following migration creating nullable foreign key column on `Child` table:

```
....

migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "Child",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
            ParentId = table.Column<int>(nullable: true)   // <--- !!
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_Child", x => x.Id);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Child_Parent_ParentId",
                column: x => x.ParentId,
                principalTable: "Parent",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
        });
```

resulting in the schema below:

[image]

**I need the FK to be non-nullable** though. How to enforce EF to do it **without** changing the model (without the necessity of introducing artificial properties only to define underlying storage relations)?

PS: In particular I want to avoid abusing the model by introducing 2-way references, only to be able to express what I need, e.g.

```
public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }   // <--- not acceptable
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Childs)
    .WithOne(c => c.Parent)
    .IsRequired();   // <--- non-null
```

Is the manual interference into the migration code the only solution (doesn't it result in mismatch with the model snapshot then)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the dependent entity has no reference navigation property on which to put `[Required]` attribute or use C# 8 non nullable reference type (e.g. `Parent` vs `Parent?`), and has no explicit FK property with non nullable type (e.g. `int` vs `int?`), the only remaining option is fluent API.

Relationship fluent API requires at least *correct* `Has` + `With` pair, and then in this particular case `IsRequired()` method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Childs) // collection navigation property
    .WithOne() // no reference navigation property
    .IsRequired();
```